# How to use YouTube API V3 for realtime subscribers

Tags: php, youtube

I'm fairly new when it comes down to API's and in specific YouTube API'S. My questions is that I'm trying to create a website where simply someone can enter a channel name, and the website will return a realitime count of the channels subscribers. I know how to generate the tokens and everything via Google's side but how would I then link my website to that to retrieve the data. For example, how would I go about writing a website that displays a textbox, whatever is in the textbox in then inserted in the url where the parameter channel name should be. I hope i've explained it well, all I basically need is help connecting to the API via PHP and how would I return data dependant upon what's in the textbox.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the Channel ID via this link:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?key={YOUR_API_KEY}&forUsername={USER_NAME}&part=id`

Then, you can use that Channel ID to follow [the docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list?hl=en#http-request) to retrieve the subscribers list.